# Querying or iterating join tables in ActiveRecord/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables:

```
Venues 
has_many :venue_intel_maps

VenueIntelMap 
belongs_to :venue
```

In the **venue_intel_map** table there's a column called **:tag_label** that I want to grab for each particular venue that has a venue_intel_map

In my controller below this returns an array of each venue where then each venue has a **venue_id**

```
 def show
    @venues = Venue.where(parent_venue_id: current_admin.parent_venue_id)
 end
```

So in my views, I can do this for particular venue.

```
- @venues.each do |venue|
  =venue.name
  =venue.address
  =venue.location
```

But because I want to get to venue_intel_maps table so I can call a column called **:tag_label** I wanted to avoided a nested each statement that might look something like this

```
- @venues.each do |venues|
    - venues.venue_intel_maps.each do |intel_maps|
          = intel_maps.tag_label
```

Is there anyway I can clean this up or any suggestions?  I was trying to play around with .joins or .selects in active record but didn't know how to successfuly do that so I can somehow put the logic in my Venues model.

**EDIT**

Would it also be better somehow to define in the controller my venue doing this?  In the views I'm going to be pulling things from my venue_intel_maps table so would this serve any advantage?

```
@venues = Venue.joins(:venue_intel_maps).where(parent_venue_id: current_admin.parent_venue_id)
```

Comment: Try venue = venue .includes(:venue_intel_maps).. Can't seem to use @ on mobile lll

Comment: Joins wouldn't preload venue_intel_maps. Gotta use includes. But yes, use it in the controller. Otherwise you can do what messanjah suggests

Answer (score 0):

depending on your Rails version, try:

```
@venues.venue_intel_maps.pluck(:tag_label)

@venues.venue_intel_maps.map(&:tag_label)
```

see: http://rubyinrails.com/2014/06/rails-pluck-vs-select-map-collect/

Answer (score 0):

You could preload (Rails 3+) the `venue_intel_maps` in the controller

```
 def show
   @venues = Venue.where(
     parent_venue_id: current_admin.parent_venue_id
   ).preload(:venue_intel_maps)
 end
```

Then in the view, use the iteration you suggested

```
- @venues.each do |venue|
  = venue.name
  = venue.address
  = venue.location
  = venue.venue_intel_maps.each do |intel_maps|
    = intel_maps.tag_label
```